# invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Blade

Tags: php, frameworks

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/securefr/public_html/resources/views/themes/gameshop/buy.blade.php)

```
<div class="row g-2 mt-3 more-info">

    @forelse($item->post_specification_form as $k => $v)

        <div class="col-6">

            <span>{{$v->field_name}}: {{$v->field_value}}</span>

        </div>

    @empty

    @endforelse

</div>
```

https://flareapp.io/share/omwQrlZ7#F62L142

Ive tried a few different answers on here, but just cant get it to shift!

Comment: `$item->post_specification_form` is not an array or an iterable object/collection. You'll need to find out what it is

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not share an exception from live app that is hosted somewhere on the web, there is too much data that can be used to do something malicious.

But using tab "App" from Flare bug, it seems that you didn't passed an argument in view or your object has missing property, so `null` is not valid argument for your foreach - that's what error message says.